# Why the selected text is not replaced with inserted in Word 2003?

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2003

I didn't notice what and when happend but from some moment replacing stopped work in Word.

Just imagine that I have a text block:

```
Some text block
```

And I select the word *text*:

Some `text` block

After that I press some key, for example, 'A'. And I expect to see

```
Some A block
```

because selected area should be replaced (as usual).

But instead of that I see:

```
Some Atext block
```

Inserted text is just appended as prefix.

Could anyone help me with this issue, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select Tools / Options
2. Select the 'Edit' tab
3. Be sure the option 'Typing replaces selection' is checked.

Comment: In Word 2007 the same option is available by clicking the Office Button > Word Options > Advanced > Editing Options section.

Comment: Awesome! I've already thought that angry virus ate Word's core :)